# java websockets & ping

Tags: java, networking, ping, java-websocket

I am discovering java API for websockets (JSR 365), and I would like to write a test that would verify that the server is run.
my question is simple : if I ping the IP adress of the computer with the server' port , will I get an answer?

thank you

ps : I add that the server is created programmatically, from a java program. There's no windows service.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "ping". You can't ICMP-Ping a port.

Comment: I meant the common ping command, available on windows.

Comment: let's forget ping : my core problem is : how to verify via the network and via a java program, that the server is running, the only unconvenient way being to write a client which would communicate with the server(because then making tests looses all its reason).